# Перегрузка и переопределение

Tags: ооп, c++

Увидел такой код:

```
class Base {
public:
  virtual void foo(int i = 0);
  virtual void foo(int i, int j):
}

class Derived {
public:
  virtual void foo(int i);
}
```

Вопрос был, что и как здесь можно вызвать?

```
int main() {
  Derived * d = new Derived();
  // Вызываем все, что можем. 
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Вот так будет

```
#include <iostream>

class Base {
public:
  virtual void foo(int i = 0) { std::cout << "base::f(int)" << std::endl; }
  virtual void foo(int i, int j) { std::cout << "base::f(int,int)" << std::endl; }
};

class Derived : public Base {
public:
  virtual void foo(int i) { std::cout << "derived::f" << std::endl; }
};

int main() {
  Derived * d = new Derived();
  Base * b = d;
  // Вызываем все, что можем.

  //d->foo();    <- ошибка компиляции
  d->foo(1);     // >> derived::f
  //d->foo(1,2); <- ошибка компиляции

  b->foo();      // >> derived::f
  b->foo(1);     // >> derived::f
  b->foo(1,2);   // >> base::f(int,int)
  return 1;
}
```

В деталях все подробно описано в стандарте, в секции: *10.3 Virtual functions*.